# CMAKE Linux Mint building gtest "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lThreads::Threads: No such file or directory"

Tags: linux, cmake, pthreads, googletest, linux-mint

CMAKE Linux Mint   building gtest

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lThreads::Threads: No such file or directory
```

This is Gtest Out of the box after `apt-get install libgtest-dev`
works PERFECT on a slightly older version ubuntu, but on Mint 21.1(??)
CMake version 3.22.1
(Yes -- I have built & installed all the libs in `/usr/src/gtest`)

reinstalled cmake && gtest n number of times, no change

Answer (score 0):

The quick / Easy fix:
Download cmake 3.16 and build
cmake-3.16.0-Linux-x86_64/bin/cmake CMakeLists.txt